# @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on org.engine.security.WebSecurityConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to run Spring Boot app which connects to remote MySQL server. I get exception during startup time:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on org.engine.security.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de8b459d@49e2b3c5, so it cannot be used on org.engine.security.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6562c81@5a484ce1 too.
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:147
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/xDguJ0Vz

Locally it's working fine. Probably the connect time to MySQL is the issue. Do you know how I can increase the connect time in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Wrong Spring Security configurations.

[Default `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s `@Order` value is `100`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.3.2.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java#L94).
When creating 2 or more `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementations, set unique value explicitly.

On your environment, `org.engine.security.WebSecurityConfig` and `org.engine.security.WebSecurityConfiguration` are ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need annotate the Configurers with a different @Order value--so like @Order(101) or something.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your SpringBoot application has two classes that 'extends' `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Option 1: Keep only one class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Option 2: If you want to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` multiple times then set explicit `@Order(1)` annotation on the class that you wish to be considered first.

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
```

Link to Spring Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/jc.html